# Black rectangles in menu bar that randomly appear

Tags: macos, bug

I recently purchased a MacBook Air M1 and it runs the latest OS version. I noticed that sometimes there is a black rectangle in the menu bar. I have attached two screen shots. I am now worried if this is a known software bug or if my device has a defect. I have not been able to find the problem on the internet. Should I replace my device? The size of the rectangle is changing in size.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might want to comment on macrumors thread https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/big-sur-orm1-menu-bar-black-strip.2286101/ and I think this has been mentioned before on reddit (not just your new post there).

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven't seen that post

Answer (score 1):

To start with I would boot your Mac into Safe Mode and determine if the rectangles still appear.

**Booting into Safe Mode on an M1 Mac**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Press the power button to start your Mac, but continue holding it down as your Mac starts up until you see the startup options window:

[image]

3. Select your startup disk, press and hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key and click the *Continue in Safe* option
4. Let go of the <kbd>shift</kbd> key
5. Log into your Mac (**Note:** you may need to do this twice)
6. Take a note of what happens (i.e. do the rectangles still appear while in Safe Mode?)
7. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
8. Test again to see if the rectangles still appear when booted normally

Once you've followed the above steps, let me know how you went and we'll go from there.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the error occurs rarely and I don't know what triggers it. So I would have to use safe mode for quite a while to check if it still occurs.

Comment: (@Gilby made a comment below my question with a link to someone that has the same problem.)